# Get unique number from array every time in range in android

Tags: java, android, arrays, hashset

I wanted to make an app which will store numbers in an array and when a button is clicked. The array will take a unique random number from the array and add it to a HashSet. This process would continue until the array gets empty. And, when the array is empty or HashSet is full, it would give a message of "Array is empty and Hashset is full".  I tried it doing by myself but i couldnot make it work.

Here is my code:
**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/array1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="172dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="130dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="152dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="276dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/array1"
        android:layout_marginStart="-37dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:text="Range from 0 to 10"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.akarki.mathgenius;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.icu.text.UnicodeSetSpanner;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Random r;
    HashSet set;
    ArrayList list;
    TextView text1;
    Button array1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        array1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.array1);
        text1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);
        set = new HashSet<Integer>();
        list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            list.add(i);
        }

        array1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                arraylist(list,set);
            }
        });

    }
    public void arraylist(ArrayList list, HashSet set){
        int random = r.nextInt(list.size());
        arrayExist((Integer) list.get(random),set);
    }
    public void arrayExist(int num,HashSet set){

        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
            if (!set.contains(num)) {
                set.add(num);
                text1.setText(num);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Unique Value",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                list.remove(num);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. It will not be repeated. The problem in my code was that I did not initiate Random object. Now, I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I write some piece code for you to figure out what problem is. Some of problems I found are that first of all `list.remove(num)` takes a parameter as `index` or an `Object`, so you should cast num as an `Integer`. Otherwise, it throws `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException`. Secondly, I cannot get the purpose of using a `for-loop` in `arrayExist` method. You won't need it, as long as you invoke `onClick` this action takes place. Here is a test code which run properly in Java.

```
@Test
public void fromArrayToSet() {

    List<Integer> list = createList();
    HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();
    System.out.println("ListBefore = " + list);
    System.out.println("SetBefore = " + set);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        arraylist((ArrayList) list, set );
    }
}

public void arraylist(List<Integer> list, HashSet set){
    int random = new Random().nextInt(list.size());
    arrayExist(list, list.get(random), set);
}

public void arrayExist(List<Integer> list ,int num, HashSet set){

    set.add(num);
    list.remove((Integer) num);

    System.out.println("ListAfter = " + list);
    System.out.println("SetAfter = " + set);
}

public List<Integer> createList() {

    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(10);
    for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
        list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
}
```